# Why is Python requests.PreparedRequest's body type bytes when json is specified and str when data is specified is passed?

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I am using `requests` library to send HTTP requests and found the following behavior bizarre: when I use `json=` to build request's body, its type becomes `bytes`, and when I use `data=` to build request's body, its type remains `str`. Is there a reason why using `json=` would lead `requests` library developers to encode the body right-away?

```
In [8]: requests.Request('GET', 'https://httpbin.org/get', json={'a': 5}).prepare().body
Out[8]: b'{"a": 5}' # bytes

In [9]: requests.Request('GET', 'https://httpbin.org/get', data=json.dumps({'a': 5})).prepare().body
Out[9]: '{"a": 5}'  # str
```

From `requests.models`:

```py
    def prepare_body(self, data, files, json=None):
        """Prepares the given HTTP body data."""

        # Check if file, fo, generator, iterator.
        # If not, run through normal process.

        # Nottin' on you.
        body = None
        content_type = None

        if not data and json is not None:
            # urllib3 requires a bytes-like body. Python 2's json.dumps
            # provides this natively, but Python 3 gives a Unicode string.
            content_type = 'application/json'

            try:
              body = complexjson.dumps(json, allow_nan=False)
            except ValueError as ve:
              raise InvalidJSONError(ve, request=self)

            if not isinstance(body, bytes):
                body = body.encode('utf-8') # !!! ACTIVELY ENCODED HERE !!!
```

Comment: Network traffic has to be `bytes`.  They're just getting prepared.

Comment: @TimRoberts but then why in the case of `data=` won't they immediately encode that into bytes? Why only in `json=` case is that done?

Comment: `data` can be several different things that might need further interpretation.  It's just a design decision.